# How can i represent image/video from byte array in angular2?

Tags: image, angular

I have byte array format from backend API. I have to display the image/video in front-end app. I don't have any idea on representing byte array as image. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
<img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Comment: :( No Luck. It is something like below 

�=�$5��M�l��԰��h��W�ێ!�r�������bm�|�>&�DﱶwOfgi����3�MS+�0P�t5�tu4ut�Z���Q�O�9=�sQv��HdA��קm����;��)�Vx�_�v�}U1���V,��ո�~����"J(�uTdѩ��&D������bK8��O���>"+҃���6��kEC���Z�c���*>�e�Z��1�*D%*�H�P~���}ib��F���������.֨�4m>:8�X���Dl[�6��MQ�+��IY�����?���і�;^��늈堍����L�.��&j�%z����4ύ-Q��"[��^=�B����q���?o�֚F9&�p������7\�O[Sngr�o%D��ȳ̳�#��gI���#��d�%
�(�$�����v0����Qn����I��sX]�w�O���k�xm��D�Jj�G�9��"d�E
3*{�dzΫ^��{��8�8zp�����V+#Qr1�����球K�:��3�Y(�ۛ1>B�z�M}�z:�ND�}b<����)-�����Dc����=z�'���

Comment: Please copy and paste above img tag in component html.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if angular has something for convert an array byte image, but you can try this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{yourByteArray}}" alt=""/>
```

Comment: unsafe:data and don't display the image